# Mongoose: Problem populating nested array with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, orm, nosql, mern

I have these models:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "profiles",
  },
});
```

And this model:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  },
  education: [
    {
      institution: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "institutions",
      },
      major: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "majors",
      },
    },
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

I've been trying to populate the `user.profile.education` `array` using `aggregate`.
Particularly, the fields `institution` and `major`.
So the expected result is the array of education to have its education elements populated.
So the expected result should be something like this:

```
[
  // user 1
  {
    profile: {
      education: [
        { institution: "institution_1_data", major: "major_1_data" },
        { institution: "institution_2_data", major: "major_2_data" },
        { institution: "institution_3_data", major: "major_3_data" },
      ],
    },
  },
  // user 2
  {
    profile: {
      education: [
        { institution: "institution_1_data", major: "major_1_data" },
        { institution: "institution_2_data", major: "major_2_data" },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

This is the query that I wrote:

```
const getUsersWithPopulatedMajorAndInstitution = async () => {
  const unwind_education_stage = {
    $unwind: "$education",
  };
  const populate_education_stage = {
    $lookup: {
      from: "majors",
      let: { major: "$education.major" },
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$major"] } } }],
      as: "education.major",
    },
    $lookup: {
      from: "institutions",
      let: { institution: "$education.institution" },
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$institution"] } } }],
      as: "education.institution",
    },
  };

  const populate_profile_stage = {
    $lookup: {
      from: "profiles",
      let: { profile_id: "$profile" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$profile_id"] },
          },
        },
        unwind_education_stage,
        populate_education_stage,
        {
          $project: {
            education: "$education",
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "profile",
    },
  };

  let users = await User.aggregate([populate_profile_stage]);

  return users;
};
```

There are two problems with this query.
**PROBLEM 1:**
It only populates institution because the `institution` `$lookup` stage was added after the `major` `$lookup` stage.
This makes no sense to me, as I've been using aggregate for a while and would expect both `major` and `institution` to be populated.

**PROBLEM 2:**
Using `$unwind` means `education` field would be unwinded.
So if the `education` array contains more than 1 education element (like the examples above), three *"copies"* of the user will be created and the end result is something like this:

```
[
  // user 1
  {
    profile: {
      education: [{ institution: "institution_1_data", major: "major_1_data" }],
    },
  },
  {
    profile: {
      education: [{ institution: "institution_2_data", major: "major_2_data" }],
    },
  },
  {
    profile: {
      education: [{ institution: "institution_3_data", major: "major_3_data" }],
    },
  },
  // user 2
  {
    profile: {
      education: [{ institution: "institution_1_data", major: "major_1_data" }],
    },
  },
  {
    profile: {
      education: [{ institution: "institution_2_data", major: "major_2_data" }],
    },
  },
];
```

But, that's not the expected result as I mentioned above.
What should I change/add in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this this way:

```
const getUsersWithPopulatedMajorAndInstitution = async (
  user_name_surname_input_value
) => {
  const unwind_education_stage = {
    $unwind: "$education",
  };

  const look_up_institution_stage = {
    $lookup: {
      from: "institutions",
      localField: "education.institution",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "education.institution",
    },
  };

  const look_up_major_stage = {
    $lookup: {
      from: "majors",
      localField: "education.major",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "education.major",
    },
  };

  const populate_stage = {
    $lookup: {
      from: "profiles",
      let: { profile_id: "$profile" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$profile_id"] },
          },
        },
        unwind_education_stage,
        look_up_major_stage,
        look_up_institution_stage,
        // This is necessary to regroup education elements after unwinding them
        {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        education: {
          $push: "$education",
        },
      },
    },
        {
          $project: {
            education: "$education",
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "profile",
    },
  };

  let filtered_users = await User.aggregate([
    populate_stage,
  ]);

  return filtered_users;
};
```